# Evaluate $\int_0^{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How to evaluate the following integral?
>   $$\int_0^{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} dx}$$

I know the answer is $\pi /2$, but how?

It was mentioned somewhere that it can be solved using $x = \sin^2 \theta$, but I don't know how.

Comment: do you mean $$\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}dx$$?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to write it with sqrt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x = \sin^2(\theta) \implies dx=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) d\theta$. Consequently,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} dx & = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) d\theta\\
& = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2(\theta)d\theta\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-\cos(2\theta)) d\theta \\
& = \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't $1-sin^2 \theta = cos^2 \theta$? so how $ sqrt{sin^2 \theta / cos^2 \theta}$ equals $2sin^2 \theta$

Comment: See the detailed solution.